# Need help for an Xpath

Tags: xpath

HTML:

[image]

I'm trying to find XPath for `div` but the following one doesn't work:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//input[contains(@data-index='1')]/div[contains(@class,'Formstyled__FidelityCardContainer-sc-1jx9mps-7 hHikVJ')]")
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Post a [mcve] of your problem, including the markup posted as text, formatted as code,.  Never post screenshots of code or data -- they're not searchable and cannot be easily used to verify proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

`[contains(@data-index='1')]` is not correct predicate. Use either

```
[contains(@data-index, '1')]
```

or

```
[@data-index='1']
```

Comment: Hello ! Thanks for the reply, i made the adjustement you said but unfortunatly It still cant find the element on the webpage when I'm using the modified Xpath...